# Does the type of project in Visual Studio matter as long as we have the correct references and configs?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I received source code of a web application for Visual Studio which its solution contains 15 different projects and I'm supposed to create something like that.

The main project is a MVC3 web application, and the rest are non web applications just for handling data and other resources.

I don't know the type of those projects while I try to add new projects to my new solution. Could I just add an empty project for example a asp.net web application empty project or anything else C# application empty project even a windows one and still make the right solution with adding right references , configure and other files? does the type of project really matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of project matters to Visual Studio because it controls the compile switches.  There are different switches to create a .dll (Class Library project) and so forth.  Visual Studio also uses the project type to determine how to run a particular project. (In the Cassini web server for websites and Web Projects, or just as an executable for Console and WinForms apps, etc.)

If you have the .csproj files, you can look in the file to determine the project type.

For example, a Class Library will have

```
<OutputType>Library</OutputType>
```

A WinForms, Console, or Windows Service app has

```
<OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
```

A Website will have no .csproj file, but you'll be able to identify that based on the existence of .aspx, .asmx, and other files.

If you DON'T have the .csproj files you'll be left to your best guess.  Generally, if it looks like a bunch of classes with no Main() function to be found, and those classes are referenced in another library, it's most likely a Class Library project.

If you see a Main() routine, it could be any of the varieties of Windows Executables, so you'll need to look for clues like the existence of Console.WriteLine() calls (usually associated with Console apps) or Windows UI components like TextBoxes, etc, and references to the System.Windows.Forms Namespace.  References to System.ServiceModel generally indicate a Windows Service, etc.

Comment: for my MVC project the OutPutType is Library but it doesn't seem right, I read with looking up the GUID of ProjectGuid determines the type but couldn't find the list of Guids on google, is it right?

Comment: MVC may very well be output as a Library.  We're one of those silly old WebForms shops that hasn't moved to MVC yet.  I don't do a lot of MVC work, so I don't have a porject handy to reference.  All of the above is based on looking at my own code base.

Comment: BTW based on what you said for different type of projects as long as the outPutType is the same there would be no problem? I created a couple more projects and they have the Library type so if I just at the references it's going to be fine?

Comment: Probably.  Your best bet is to try it and see. The worst-case scenario will be that you need to undo your work and redo it.  I wish I were there to look at the code myself. I'd probably be more help that way.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I'll post the result ;)